# How to create a new target segment in Trados SDL 2015 API?

Tags: api

My goal is to implement a translation helper plugin for Trados SDL 2015 CAT tool.
Creating and registering a plugin works well, and the plugin can read the selected source segment well.

My goal is to automatically process the selected source segment, and write data to the selected target segment. It is important to be able to write tags and formatting settings too.

Changing the text of an existing target segment is also working fine.

However when the target segment is empty, none of my approaches seem to work, and because of that, I can not set any text for an empty target segment.

The same problem is described here: https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/language/language-developers/f/57/t/2315

We are new to Trados API, and wondering if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not migrated to Trados Studio 2015 yet, and I am pretty sure that SDL have changed the Studio APIs since the 2014 version. Still, could you perhaps check if there is a class called SourceToTargetCopier in the 2015 version of `Sdl.FiletypeSupport.Core.Utilities.BilingualApi`? If it still exists you could use the `ProcessParagraphUnit` method to fill any empty target segments with the source content.

Comment: Wow, thanks, this looks promising, I'll look into this asap!